# Update dynamic height when adding dynamic textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my page I have 2 floated divs, lets call them div.left and div.right. I am using jQuery to add the height of div.right to div.left .

div.right is basically full of input fields and I am using jquery to add more textboxes on button click. Problem is when I add more textboxes the height of div.left does not update.

A basic version of my HTML looks like this:

```
    <div class="left" style="float:left"></div>
    <div class="right" style="float:right">
         <input type="text" name="textbox" />
         <input type='button' value='Add another' id='AddButton'> 
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

In this case #AddButton will add another textbox.

The jQuery to add height to div.left:

```
     $(window).load(function () {
        var MainHeight = $('div.left');
        $('div.right').css('height', (MainHeight.height()) + 'px');
    });
```

I am using this to add textboxes http://www.naragoni.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/

How would I update the height of div.left as div.right increases?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Add below line at the end of **$("#addButton").click(function () {** and    **$("#removeButton").click(function () {**  functions (these two functions you will get from this code :  http://www.naragoni.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/)

```
$('div.right').height($('#TextBoxesGroup').height());
```

or use div id to set height like below

```
$('#rightDivID').height($('#leftDivID').height());
```

Please let me know if you have any query.

Thank you...